# Bubble in Graphic program

Tags: java, android, gesture, graphic, intersect

Hey all

I have a program that draw a bubble anywhere by touching the screen (gesture detector),
I want to handle an issue not to draw two bubbles at the same position by intersect method 
how can I do that ?**

Comment: private synchronized boolean intersects(float x, float y) { }

Comment: Can you maybe show what you have done so far? There are dozens of ways to do that

Comment: i want to check if the new drawn bubble's position is interesected with one already drawn or not ,any help!

Comment: public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {

 
                 for(int i=0;i<mFrame.getChildCount();i++){
             BubbleView bubbleNew= (BubbleView) mFrame.getChildAt(i);
 if(bubbleNew.intersects(event.getX(),event.getY())){
                 bubbleNew.stop(true);
                     
        }
      }
   BubbleView bubbleNew= new BubbleView(mFrame.getContext(),event.getX(),event.getY());
   bubbleNew.start();
   mFrame.addView(bubbleNew);        return false;
   }
  });

Comment: If you want to add information to your question, especially snippets of code, you'll get a more readable result if you use the **edit** link under the question, than if you use the comment field.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you have some kind of collection for your existing bubbles.  Whenever you have a new bubble, use something like this to find out whether it intersects any of the bubbles in the collection.  If not, then draw it and add it to the collection.

```
import java.util.Collection;

public class Bubble {
    private int centreX;
    private int centreY;
    private int radius;

    public Bubble(int centreX, int centreY, int radius) {
        this.centreX = centreX;
        this.centreY = centreY;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public boolean intersectsAny(Collection<Bubble> others){
        for (Bubble other : others) {
            if (intersects(other)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean intersects(Bubble other) {
        int distanceSquared = (centreX - other.centreX) * (centreX - other.centreX)
            + (centreY - other.centreY) * (centreY - other.centreY);
        return distanceSquared <= (radius + other.radius) * (radius + other.radius);
    }
}
```